# make array instead string in php

Tags: javascript, php

ajax call with this `data` variable gives expected POST data in the controller(server)

```
Javascript:
var data = "item[]=9&item[]=1&item[]=2&item[]=3&item[]=4&item[]=5&item[]=6&item[]=7&item[]=8"
$.ajax({
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/call'
});
```

---

```
Controller:
array:1 [
  "item" => array:9 [
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "4"
    3 => "3"
    4 => "5"
    5 => "6"
    6 => "7"
    7 => "8"
    8 => "9"
  ]
]
```

in my requirement, I create a new variable

```
Javascript:
var data = "item[]=9&item[]=1&item[]=2&item[]=3&item[]=4&item[]=5&item[]=6&item[]=7&item[]=8"
var = other_parameters => [
      "host" => "host name"
      "session" => "current session"
      "timestamp" => "time stamp"
]

let requestData = {
     other_parameters,
     data
}

$.ajax({
    data: requestData,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/call'
});
```

---

```
Controller(Currently I get this data in the controller):
array:2 [
  "other_parameters" => array:3 [
      "host" => "host name"
      "session" => "current session"
      "timestamp" => "time stamp"
  ]
  "data" => "item[]=1&item[]=2&item[]=3&item[]=5&item[]=4&item[]=6&item[]=7&item[]=8&item[]=9"
]

Expected:
array:2 [
    "other_parameters" => array:3 [
        "host" => "host name"
        "session" => "current session"
        "timestamp" => "time stamp"
    ],
    "data" => [
        "item" => array:9 [
            0 => "1"
            1 => "2"
            2 => "4"
            3 => "3"
            4 => "5"
            5 => "6"
            6 => "7"
            7 => "8"
            8 => "9"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Please help to get expected data in Controller(Server)

Comment: How exactly does your API call endpoint return the data? Are you just rendering a string there?

Comment: You need to append the other values to the `data` string in the same format. Either that or convert the whole thing to an object structure in JS and pass that object to jQuery. What's happening now is a hybrid system which doesn't work: you're putting `data` into the object as a string. jQuery then form-url-encodes your whole object before sending it in the request. It doesn't take account that `data` is already an encoded string, it just treats it as a plain text property of the object, and thus so does PHP.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this really a PHP problem, or a pure JS problem?

Comment: I rolled back your [recent edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69768485/revisions). Don't change your question to a fundamentally different one after it's already been answered and commented on - it makes the existing contributions from other people make less/no sense, which is unhelpful for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and use `parse_str`, REF: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Example:

```
$str = 'item[]=1&item[]=2&item[]=3&item[]=5&item[]=4&item[]=6&item[]=7&item[]=8&item[]=9'
parse_str($str, $output);
var_dump($output);

// Output
array:1 [▼
  "item" => array:9 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "3"
    3 => "5"
    4 => "4"
    5 => "6"
    6 => "7"
    7 => "8"
    8 => "9"
  ]
]
```

It should get you to where you need to be.

**Edit:**

A better way would probably be to convert all your data into a JSON array first and send that. Then just use `json_decode` to get your array in PHP.

Comment: This might work but it's a sticking plaster to cover up the fact the data is sent in a jumbled format to begin with. Nothing against your solution, I just feel it's worth mentioning this is more of a workaround than a proper fix (a fix which is within the OP's power, since they also wrote the JS).